# How to handle "There is no row at position 1" error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im pretty new in ASP.NET
Over here I dont have any rows at Rows[1][...] But i want to check whether there is anything there or not
if there is no Row at Row[1][...] then i want to proceed so I handled it like this in the ternary operator in the line `Statement = (dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString()==""?"": dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString());`
Below is the rest of the code including this line

```
 DataTable dtEntryFlag= objdalTransactionEntry.GetRentInvoiceEntryFlag(Sessions.Name.UserId);
      string Statement="";
      if (dtEntryFlag.Rows.Count>0)
      {
         Statement = (dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString()==""?"": dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString()); 
///the line above that needs fixing
      }
```

Comment: I wonder if you realize arrays in c# are 0-based. So to get the first item you should do `dtEntryFlag.Rows[0]`. hard to debug tho, because we lack the knowledge of what does `dtEntryFlag` contain.

Comment: Cleptus the Counter is a iterator variable so it iterates from 0 to 1 to 2 and so on
So the table has 1 row and it could increase depending on data so when the counter is 0 its fine when the counter reaches 1 i get this error so i want a condition like if there is now Row after Row[0]

Comment: Then you need to iterate based on the row count. Something like: `for (int i=0; i < dtEntryFlag.Rows.Count; i++)`.

Comment: In Net the row count is -1 until columns are added and then when column are added the cound goes to zero.  So best test for rows is either >= 0  or > 0.

Comment: If the value is am empty string, then use an empty string, else use the value - why not use that value immediately,  without the conditional?

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this issue is to not access the row entirely if it doesn't exist. Check in if condition.

```
DataTable dtEntryFlag = objdalTransactionEntry.GetRentInvoiceEntryFlag(Sessions.Name.UserId);
string Statement = "";
if (counter < dtEntryFlag.Rows.Count)
{
    Statement = (dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString() == "" ? "" : dtEntryFlag.Rows[counter]["EntryFlag"].ToString());
}
```